# Fixed table width and overflow:auto. How get it to scroll?

Tags: wordpress, scroll, html-table, width, overflow

I'm trying to understand coding of my Wordpress site better, so I set my mind on eliminating as much as plugins as possible, starting with a table plugin which shouldn't be very hard..

I want the table to show in a fixed width (756px) and I want it to scroll if the content is viewed on smaller displays or when the browser window is resized. The goal is to keep the table layout exactly the same.

The problem is that when I specify a width, the table just gets clipped without the option to scroll and when I set the width to 100% the table resizes which I don't want.

I tried reverse engineering the plugin I use, but I guess I don't have the knowledge yet to pull it off.

It's taken a long time now and I just want to move on to the next obstacle:)

[Table so far](http://travelaar.nl/tabel-test/)

html:

```
<div class="tabel">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Eten &amp; Drinken<br /><img src="http://travelaar.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/eten-en-drinken-kraam.png" /></th>
            <th>Slapen<br /><img src="http://travelaar.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/slapen.png" /></th>
            <th>Vervoer<br /><img src="http://travelaar.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/vervoer-trein-icon.png" /></th>
            <th>Excursies<br /><img src="http://travelaar.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/excursies.png" /></th>
            <th>Overige<br /><img src="http://travelaar.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/overige.png" /></th>
            <th>Totaal</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&#8369; 35.460,05</td>
            <td>&#8369; 30.484,84</td>
            <td>&#8369; 16.254,76</td>
            <td>&#8369; 5.836,00</td>
            <td>&#8369; 4.086,28</td>
            <td>&#8369; 92.121,93</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&#8364;673,74</td>
            <td>&#8364;579,21</td>
            <td>&#8364;308,84</td>
            <td>&#8364;110,88</td>
            <td>&#8364;77,64</td>
            <td>&#8364;1.750,32</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

css:

```
.tabel {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(top left, rgba(185,204,102,0.5),      rgba(144,72,138,0.5));
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 3px solid black;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
tr, th, td {
  text-align:center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
th {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: I tried this using Chrome, Safari, and Firefox (all on Mac), it scrolls horizontally in a narrow frame as written above (I made no changes). Here's a jsbin, see if you get the same result - https://jsbin.com/fuvehe/2/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out.. For anyone interested.. here is the result and the answer.

html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="livecss.css">
</head>
<body>
    <table class="tabel">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="6">Indonesi&euml; - 29 dagen</th>
      </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Eten &amp; Drinken<br /><img src="http://travelaar.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/eten-en-drinken-kraam.png" /></th>
            <th>Slapen<br /><img src="http://travelaar.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/slapen.png" /></th>
            <th>Vervoer<br /><img src="http://travelaar.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/vervoer-trein-icon.png" /></th>
            <th>Excursies<br /><img src="http://travelaar.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/excursies.png" /></th>
            <th>Overige<br /><img src="http://travelaar.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/overige.png" /></th>
            <th>Totaal</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&#8369; 35.460,05</td>
            <td>&#8369; 30.484,84</td>
            <td>&#8369; 16.254,76</td>
            <td>&#8369; 5.836,-</td>
            <td>&#8369; 4.086,28</td>
            <td>&#8369; 92.121,93</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&#8364; 673,74</td>
            <td>&#8364; 579,21</td>
            <td>&#8364; 308,84</td>
            <td>&#8364; 110,88</td>
            <td>&#8364; 77,64</td>
            <td>&#8364; 1.750,32</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

css (including custom scrollbars;))

```
/*TABEL CSS*/
table {
    overflow-x: auto;
    font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    /*background: -webkit-radial-gradient(top left, rgba(185,204,102,0.5), rgba(144,72,138,0.5))*/
    border-collapse: collapse;
    display: block;
        table-layout: fixed;
    border-style: hidden;
}
th, td {
  border: 1px solid white;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
th {
    text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #b9cc66;
    padding: 5px;
}
td {
    text-align: right;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
  background-color: rgba(144,72,138,0.5)
}

.tabel tr > td:last-of-type {
    background-color: rgba(144,72,138,0.8)
}

  /*SCROLLBAR STYLE*/
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
      width: 12px;
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
      height: 12px;
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      border-radius: 10px;
      border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      border-radius: 10px;
      background-color: rgba(185,204,102,0.2);
  }
  /*EINDE SCROLLBAR STYLE*/
/*EINDE TABEL CSS*/
```

Comment: OP had taken the time to explain his answer and include all code, and the answer gets downvoted by someone. Sheesh. I've upvoted it.